# Execute "multiple" JPA transactions into a single "transaction"

Tags: java, jpa, transactions

I have two separate JPA transactions T1() and T2():

```
public void T1() {
    em = getEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    ...
    //some statements
    ...
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

and

```
public void T2() {
    em = getEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    ...
    //some statements
    ...
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Now, i have a combined transaction that requires the execution of T1() and T2() is needed.

The following code sample should be buggy:

```
public void T12() {
    em = getEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    T1();
    T(2)
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

The following code does not ensure the failure or the success of the T1() AND T2() because if T1() succeed, T2() can fail without being able to rollback T1():

```
public void T12() {
    T1();
    T(2);
}
```

**Should I change the design of T1() (and T2()) as follows:**

```
public void T1(EntityTransaction trans) {
    if (trans != null) {
        trans.begin();
    }
    ...
    //some statements
    ...
    if (trans != null) { 
        trans.commit();
    }
}
```

When executed as standalone transaction, i use:

```
void singleTransction() {
    ...
    trans = em.getTransaction();
    trans.begin();
    T1(trans); 
    trans.commit();
}
```

When executed in already started transaction, i use:

```
void manyTransactions() {
    ....
    trans = em.getTransaction();
    trans.begin();
    T1(null);
    T2(null);
    T3(null);
    trans.commit();
}
```

I am not sure about the design i suggested.

What do you suggest instead?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what your question is about? I cannot find a question in your post :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JTA and `em.joinTransaction()`.

Or you can check to see if you need to begin/commit within your methods. The ideas is to have your methods be smart enough to manage a transaction if there is not one already and not manage a transaction if the caller is managing it.

```
public void T1() {
    em = getEntityManager();
    boolean managingTransaction = !em.getTransaction.isActive();
    if (managingTransaction) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
    }
    ...
    //some statements
    ...
    if (managingTransaction) {
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

This works, assuming that the `getEntityManager()` gives you the same entity manager every time you call it within the same thread (which is the typical pattern).

I will also note that you need additional error handling code to `rollback()` the transaction as necessary (I assume you know that, but someone coming to look at this question may not realize that your code is not a complete example).

Comment: I think it is a good pattern. It does not require any modification in the caller functions. It can be executed as standalone transaction that commits the changes, as well as an embedded set of statements with is executed within a transaction initialized by the caller.

Answer (score 0):

I probably change the design and have the entity manager as an argument to the queries that are going to be performed.

```
public void T1(EntityManager manager) {
    // do work with entity manager
}

public void T2(EntityManager manager) {
    // do work with entity manager
}


//This is pseudo - example code. It won't compile
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransactions().begin();
    T1(manager);
    T2(manager);
    tx.commit();
}
```

That will elevate the transaction management above the executing queries and seperate concerns nicely (as far as I can see);

Comment: If you follow this pattern, in practice you end up passing the EM to every method you write. Yuck. The alternative that is usually used is to make the EM available everywhere by stashing it in a ThreadLocal variable (and access it via a call like 'getEntityManager()`).

Comment: Agreed, I was trying to illustrate the idea of having transactions managed outside the context of the executing method. My preferred mechanism would be the JTA. The other proposed solution would require a significant amount of code duplication, which admittedly, could be re factored into some sort of specialisation.